# C# - Convert Bytes Representing Char Numbers to Int16

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, io

If I have a byte array representing a number read from a file, how can the byte array be converted to an Int16/short?

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{45,49,54,50 }  //Byte array representing "-162" from text file

short value = 0; //How to convert to -162 as a short here?
```

Tried using BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0), but the value is not correct.

Edit: Looking for a solution that does NOT use string conversion.

Comment: You'll want to convert those to a string and then parse the string.

Comment: (short)BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes)

Comment: Actually looking for a solution that uses the LEAST amount of memory (trying to avoid string conversion)

Comment: Try reverse array and then use bitconverter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function performs some validations that you may be able to exclude. You could simplify it if you know your input array will always contain at least one element and that the value will be a valid Int16.

```
    const byte Negative = (byte)'-';
    const byte Zero = (byte)'0';
    static Int16 BytesToInt16(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (null == bytes || bytes.Length == 0)
            return 0;
        int result = 0;
        bool isNegative = bytes[0] == Negative;
        int index = isNegative ? 1 : 0;
        for (; index < bytes.Length; index++)
        {
            result = 10 * result + (bytes[index] - Zero);
        }
        if (isNegative)
            result *= -1;
        if (result < Int16.MinValue)
            return Int16.MinValue;
        if (result > Int16.MaxValue)
            return Int16.MaxValue;
        return (Int16)result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like willaien said, you want to first convert your bytes to a string.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 45,49,54,50 };
string numberString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
short value = Int16.Parse(numberString);
```

If you're not sure that your string can be parsed, I recommend using `Int16.TryParse`:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 45,49,54,50 };
string numberString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
short value;

if (!Int16.TryParse(numberString, out value))
{
    // Parsing failed
}
else
{
    // Parsing worked, `value` now contains your value.
}
```

Comment: Actually looking for a solution that uses the LEAST amount of memory (trying to avoid string conversion)